# How to setup a dependency on a value coming from a server in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

All,

NOTE (my setup):

-knockout JS lib

-knockout mapping lib (my view-model is generated on the server and converted to observable VM using knockout mapping js lib)

I have an invoice form and every time a user changes one of the following values:

Qty, Unit Price

I would like to go to the server to calculate total tax and render that tax in a span.

I'm looking for piece of code in knockout that returns the computed total tax value returned from the server asynchronously and it includes dependency chain on qty and unit price. The difficulty here is that the server calls are async and how do I trigger a refresh in knockout.

UPDATE:

I resorted to the solution below, please suggest if there's better answer. Only downside to this solution is when the form is being databound the onchange  event fires for all controls that have this event binding (so that's once per line item):

```
<input data-bind="value: Quantity, event:{ change: calculateTax()}"  />

<td data-bind="text: renderCurrency(tax())"></td>


vm.tax = ko.observable(0);

function calculateTax() {
    var document = ko.mapping.toJS(vm).Document;
    var json = JSON.stringify(document);
    svc.GetTax(json, 
        function(results, ctx, methodName) {
            var mny = results;
            vm.tax(mny.Amount);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you consider making the second part either an integral part of the post or a seperate answer. Also, please make sure your question contains an [mcve] (I saw your comment to the answer mentioning after the fact that you have ko.mapping, these things are important to know up front when we're helping with finding a solution).

Comment: My bad, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of cases I've used what I call an asyncComputed. It will allow the tax value to depend on one or more observables (quantity, unit price) and update whenever a result is returned from the server. Here's one possible implementation:

```
ko.asyncComputed = function (fn, defaultValue) {
  var value = ko.observable defaultValue

  var result = ko.computed(() => value())

  result.loading = ko.observable(true)

  ko.computed(function () {
    result.loading(true)

    Promise.resolve(fn()).then(function (asyncResult) {
      result.loading(false)
      value(asyncResult)
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Note that the fn parameter is expected to be a function returning a Promise, which is what for example jQuery's ajax already does.

Assuming the svc.GetTax returns a Promise, this is how to apply it in your case:

```
vm.tax = ko.asyncComputed(function () {
  var document = ko.mapping.toJS(vm).Document;
  var json = JSON.stringify(document);
  return svc.GetTax(json).then((results) => results.Amount);
}
```

Comment: The keywords, then() and lambda expression, are these valid EcmaScript? Or they are part of a library? Can you explain?

Comment: The arrow function and Promise (and then, a function in the Promise instance) are part of Ecmascript 6. They are quite well supported by today. If you need to support old browsers you may replace the promise pattern with a callback and the fat arrow with plain old function definition.

Comment: Thanks Don. 1 more question about solution: It appears that the async computed will run if any properties on the document change, I just want an async request when either the qty, or unit price change. See, my async contract takes a Document but I only want to run it when qty, unit price change. How do I specify to knockout to only compute on those 2 properties?

Comment: Like any Knockout computed, it subscribes to every observable that is evaluated while the computed is evaluating. To make it subscribe to only those two values, you could call GetTax like GetTax({qty: vm.Document.qty(), unitPrice: vm.Document.unitPrice()})

Comment: Well, my setup is a bit more complicated because I have Document.LineItems (as in many) and each line item has qty, unitPrice ... yea, ... but the tax is calculated on the entire document. It would be nice in knockout to find out which observables changed.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what knockout's dependency tracking does well. The problem you face is because of the ko.mapping.toJS call which unnecessarily evaluates (and so subscribes to) every observable instead of only those you really need to. I'd advice you to provide vm.Document (without unmapping it) to GetTax function and in its implementation evaluate only the needed fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subscribe` in the `observable` that is a PubSub pattern implemented in the KO, [more info](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables), 
See the example:

```js
function ViewModel (){
  this.Quantity =ko.observable();
  this.tax = ko.observable();
    
  this.Quantity.subscribe(function(){
      this.calculeTax();
  },this);
};

ViewModel.prototype.calculeTax = function(){
  //Here you will do the ajax call
  this.tax(this.Quantity()*10);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: Quantity"  />
<br/>

<span>If you want to update on keydown use the textInput bind handler:<span>
  <br/>
<input data-bind="textInput: Quantity"  />
<br/>
<br/>

<span data-bind="text: tax"></span>
```

Comment: Thx for your response. One thing: 1) I do NOT have access to my ViewModel declaratively, it is generated using ko.mapping.fromJS() from the server. This makes adding your suggestion more difficult.